# Data-Mining or KDD of database

Tags: mariadb

I created some databases for technical support for electrical engineering. My problem is: How to Connect my database with MATLAB or python to execute datamining. How can I write the program for Datamining.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Is this for a class/course you're doing? If so, you should have received some instruction from your teacher/lecturer? A search for "python connect to postgresql tutorial" gives 1.2M links! The first one (commandprompt.com) looks fairly good. Try and go through it step by step and come back to us when you're stuck on a particular step - your question, as it stands, is too broad and general. This is a Q&A site - a tutorial is too long to give here - please take the site tour and go through the help (very bottom of the page) to see what we do here.